# Is the Help and Improvement review queue Filter broken?

Tags: bug, review-queues, help-improvement

## Update: This appears to be fixed now

---

**Edit: Looks like this may be specific to the [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag.**

> I think it has to do with ANY question tagged "javascript". I found a "javascript, raphael, jsplumb" tagged question and NONE of these tags can retrieve the question.
>
> –  [Patrice (comment)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294195/is-the-help-and-improvement-review-queue-filter-broken?noredirect=1#comment193117_294195)

---

If I select to *filter* the Help and Improvement review queue by the tag "javascript", I'm returned the following message:

> There are no items for you to review, matching the filter "[javascript]"

This doesn't appear to happen with other tags.

Upon removing the filter, the first question I'm greeted with ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/8016605)) has the [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag on it.

JavaScript is the second most popular tag on Stack Overflow, so I highly doubt none of the almost 600 unreviewed *Help and Improvement* questions available have the tag. And it would be a pretty large coincidence that this particular question was added to the queue the moment I removed the resultless filter.

What's going on?

---

> maybe the question appeared in the queue between the two events?

I don't think so. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/8034901) was the next one after I reviewed the previous one, also tagged with [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/8045634) is another one.

---

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: maybe the question appeared in the queue between the two events?

Comment: @Patrice I doubt it. This was the next one: http://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/8034901, also tagged with JavaScript. Also if I add the JavaScript tag back in with this review still unreviewed it doesn't appear.

Comment: then my backup idea was to blame caching :P.

Comment: OH! then adding it back without it showing, yeah that does change everything :p

Comment: @Patrice furthermore there are almost 600 questions in the review and JavaScript is the second most popular tag on SO. I can't imagine of the 600 there none have the tag.

Comment: did you spell it wrong when typing it into the filter?

Comment: @Servy if I spelled it incorrectly the error message would reflect that.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Unless you typed out a different tag that was also a tag, but that wasn't the actual javascript tag.  People create tags of common typos often, and they take a day to get cleaned up.

Comment: weirdly enough, I tried random tags, and it works (I tried bootstrap). I also did try javascript, no dice

Comment: @Patrice interestingly I can also filter by other tags. It seems to be a JavaScript tag-specific problem.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly I think it has to do with ANY question tagged "javascript", not searching with the javascript tag. I found a "javascript, raphael, jsplumb" tagged question and NONE of these tags can retrieve the question.

Comment: @Patrice I've quoted that into the question. Very strange issue!

Comment: Faced similar issue with JavaScript filter.

Comment: I actually [asked a very similar question a while back](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291245/clicking-on-a-tag-for-the-help-improvement-queue-does-not-show-questions-with), but didn't notice if it was specific to `javascript`.

Comment: I found same problem. Filter with php tag says ` There are no items for you to review, matching the filter "[php]"` but if I remove the filter I see php questions